# Use mysql joins to count no of invoices of customers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

My `invoices` table has `orderId` column which is a foreign key referencing `orderId primary key column of orders table` and orders table has `customerId` column which references to `customerId` primary key column of customers table. 
A customer can have multiple orders but an order has only one invoice.

I want to count the no of invoices of each customer. Below is the query I tried:

```
SELECT customers.name, COUNT(*) as number_of_invoices 
FROM invoices 
JOIN orders 
ON invoices.orderId = orders.orderId 
JOIN customers 
ON orders.customerId = customers.customerId;
```

But it is only returning me one customer and the count is of total count not invoices count of that customer.

Comment: You need to add `GROUP BY customers.name` at the end.

Comment: @Brainy Prb if you find this solution useful then please accept my answer as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem:

```
SELECT customers.name, COUNT(*) as number_of_invoices 
FROM invoices 
INNER JOIN orders 
ON invoices.orderId = orders.orderId 
INNER JOIN customers 
ON orders.customerId = customers.customerId
GROUP BY Customers.name;
```

Just add `GROUP BY` in your query in last to group count of invoices for each Customer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know the count of invoice for each customer. It can be done without `JOIN`. Since order and invoice has one-to-one mapping you can use below sql queries

```
select customerId ,count(orderId) as invoice_count from orders group by customerId
```

Comment: nice but I need the name of the customer too, so joins is mandatory right ?

Comment: nope, you can use inline queries too. I hate `JOIN` :). Inline queries are more readable.

Comment: Still, if you want to use `JOIN` you can achieve this only with two tables orders and customers. You don't need invoices until unless you need any column from invoices table.